# Why does the navigation file have two userMessage in Android Studio?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

The following code is from the project architecture-samples. You can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml).

Why does the navigation file have two `userMessage` in Android Studio?

BTW, and the app can run after I delete the last `<argument android:name="userMessage"  android:defaultValue="0" />`

And more, in my mind the element `<navigation>` include only child element `<fragment>`, why can the following element `<navigation>` include child element  `<argument>` ?

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/tasks_fragment_dest">
    ... 
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tasks_fragment_dest"
        android:name="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_tasksFragment_to_statisticsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/statistics_fragment_dest" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_tasksFragment_to_taskDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/task_detail_fragment_dest" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_tasksFragment_to_addEditTaskFragment"
            app:destination="@id/add_edit_task_fragment_dest" />
        <argument
            android:name="userMessage"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
    </fragment>

    <argument
        android:name="userMessage"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a typo. The second

```
    <argument
    android:name="userMessage"
    android:defaultValue="0" />
```

should be removed. The code is fine without it. The parsing of the navigation would ignore the second userMessage.

Probably the developers didn't catch it because there was no error or loss of functionality as a result.